# More efficient way of looping this Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, dataframe

I have a big dataset with the following:

Columns: Year, Country, Item, Element, Value & Others
There are like 15 years, 200 countries, 23 items.

Say for example:

```
Year Country Item Element Value
2011 Afghanistan Carbohydrates Export 123
2012 Afghanistan Stones Export 12314
2013 Afghanistan Batteries Import 5424
```

So far I have done this:

```
for year in database["Year"].unique():
    for country in database["Country"].unique():
        for item in database["Item"].unique():
            newrow = {"Element": database.loc[(database["Country"] == country) & (database["Year"] == year) & (database["Item"] == item) & (database["Element"] == "Import")].Value.item()/database.loc[(database["Country"] == country) & (database["Year"] == year) & (database["Item"] == item) & (database["Element"] == "Export").Value.item()}
            database = database.append(newrow, ignore_index=True)
```

Is there a way to do this more efficiently?

O(x*y*z) seems too high for me.

EDIT: Expected output:

```
    Year Country Item Element Value
2011 Afghanistan Carbohydrates Export 123
2012 Afghanistan Stones Export 12314
2013 Afghanistan Batteries Import 5424
2011 Afghanistan Carbohydrates Export/Import Rate 123/23123
```

For each year, country and item.

Comment: What do you want to do finally? What is your expected output? I'm sure you won't have to loop 3 times.

Comment: What you see my friend @NYCCoder. Create a new row based on 2 Elements (Import/Export) which is held by each Item (Goods) by Country and Year.

Comment: Could you add the expected output with the sample you posted?

Comment: Create new row with what data? And what conditions? Please write it in the question in simple words.

Comment: Added expected output @MrNobody33

Comment: @Vioxini could you explain the condition? I supposed `element` is `export/import` because for that country after 2011 there was another export, but the value `123/23123`, where did it comes from?

Comment: Can't you abstract yourself? I think it is well explained. There will be `15 unique Years 200 unique Countries 23 unique Items` Then in Elements, I have the following `Export Value`, `Import Value` and their respective values. So I will create a new row which is Value from `Year == year, Country == country, Item == item` from `Export Value` divided by Value from `Year == year, Country == country, Item == item` from `Import Value`. @MrNobody33

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create Export and Import DataFrame

```
df_import = df[ df['Element'] == 'Import' ]
df_export = df[ df['Element'] == 'Export' ]
```

Merge them on Year, Country, and Item into a new DataFrame. You can call it, df_exim.

```
df_exim = pd.merge(df_import, df_export, on=['Year', 'Country', 'Item'])
```

Create a new column called Rate

```
df_exim['Rate'] = df_exim['Export'] / df_exim['Import']
```

Comment: This answer looks decent. But well, making a Import Value still implies having to loop each country and year, doesn't it? Only I can think of is arrange it properly so I'd have Import and Export ordered and then I can do a numpy substraction to create the new rows. What could I do if some of the dataframes do not have the same exact "Items" as the others?

Comment: It is O(n^2) instead of O(n^3). If you want O(n), your data should have columns Import and Export in the same data frame.

Comment: You can merge using inner join. Items which are in both table will be merged.

Comment: Still have to keep the rows, don't I? Honestly, unless I make good arrays for numpy substraction/division, still will have to be O(xyz) given still has to loop country, year and item

Comment: What are you talking about keeping the rows?  df['Element'] == 'Import' O(n) df_import = df[...] O(n) merging O(n^2) df_exim['Rate']  O(n)

Comment: You don' loop country, year, and item. You select the value based on these values.

Comment: Your solution gave me a full Country, Year and Item dataset. "Rate" didn't work since "Export" and "Import" are string elements from "Element" not column themselves.

Comment: Still need Import/Export for every Year, Country and Item.

Comment: You can rename the column when merging. It is code fragments.

Comment: You get the Value column from df_import, rename it to Import and Value column from df_export, rename it to Export.

Comment: What difference does it make? Still have to loop Year, Country and Item although you have "Import" and "Export" in columns. That is still O(xyz)

Comment: To divide the numbers, it is O(n) df_exim['Rate'] = df_exim['Export'] / df_exim['Import'].

Comment: But that doesn't solve O(xyz) by Country, Year and Item.

Comment: It is not looping country, year.  Merge operations can be implemented efficiently. Get the job done in O(n^2).  Country, Year, Item can be concatenated as a key. The tables can be merged based on the key.

Comment: OHHHH!! I wasn't understanding. This reduced my time a lot. But it is a bit different of how you explain there. It creates a merged dataframe with Value_x as Export and Value_y as Import. Then you have to do df["Rate"] = df["Value_x"] / df["Value_y"]. It went from O(xyz) to O(n) or even less. Vectorized Numpy Operations are really more efficient than for loops.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for groupby.

df = df.groupby(['Year', 'Country', 'Item'])['Element'].sum()

df_import = df.loc['Elements'='import']
df_export = df.loc['Elements'='export']

Rename the value column for both dfs.
Merge dfs on index.
Create new column based on import and export column.

Comment: This answer looks decent. But well, making a Import Value still implies having to loop each country and year, doesn't it? Only I can think of is arrange it properly so I'd have Import and Export ordered and then I can do a numpy substraction to create the new rows. What could I do if some of the dataframes do not have the same exact "Items" as the others?

Comment: I think it is linear time not polynomial.

Comment: You could use regex to format the different item types first. Get the unique values and see what can be done.

Comment: Still x*y*z, @Isaac Ng, given though it is in the same dataframe, it still haves to loop through year, country and item

Comment: You only need to loop through once. For each row. Store it in a dictionary. If present, append. That is O(n) for loop and O(1) for dictionary lookup which is implemented as hash table or hash map.